# Ratchet websocket server without shell

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

I'm starting to use/learn ratchet. My goal is to write a Realtime-WebApp. But I have some general questions about ratchet.

Do I have to run a php-server-script all the time (when server boots till shutdown) to process realtime requests?

Are php-server-scripts required or are there use-cases in which no seperate php-server-script is needed (e.g. running a messagequese like redis or zeromq) [yes, I use redis too].

It would be very kind if someone could answer me these questions. The more info the better ;)

In the meantime I tried to get the Chat-App working. I'm on a good way

Thanks in advance!